# HTTP request to unavailable resource gives different error message

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, linux-networking

I have Ubuntu 18.04 client and I try to curl to the HOST that is not present on the network like:

```
curl 192.168.11.1 --connect-timeout 10
curl 192.168.11.1 --connect-timeout 35
```

Why does it sometimes respond with

`curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.11.1 port 80: No route to host`,

and sometimes with

`curl: (28) Connection timed out after 35001 milliseconds`,

even on the same timeout?

---

I also tried making HTTP request with `NodeJS`'s http request library from the same Ubuntu client. And sometimes I get

`Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.168.9.1:80` and other times I get

`Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 192.168.9.1:80`.

Comment: I believe this question belongs in the Network Engineering stack exchange.

Comment: Is the destination (192.168.11.1) on the same network or a different one? Does the traceroute sometimes work or always fails, but with different messages? Please provide more information.

Comment: The destination is not on the network, I disconnected it from the network intentionally. So it cannot be reached.

Comment: Please update your question with this and more relevant information.

Comment: Sorry, if you type `curl 192.168.11.1 --connect-timeout 35` on your PC, that is connected only to the Internet, and repeat that several times, I think you can reporoduce the error?

Answer (score 1):

One error message tells you that the whole of 192.168.9.1 cannot be reached (EHOSTUNREACH) and the other tells you that you've reached a time out waiting for a response (ETIMEDOUT), but you can't possibly know if the host is reachable or not (so YES is assumed).

EHOSTUNREACH means either your own host or a router in between is telling you it was no routes to reach that host, so it is effectively unreachable. The RFC says that such ICMP message should be returned to the sender: http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/icmp/msg3.htm .
Please note how curl adds extra info to the message by adding "no route to host". This might also be the case if there's no response to ARP resolution requests for 192.168.9.1 when you're in the same broadcast domain.

ETIMEDOUT means either the traffic was delivered to the host and it didn't respond, or the traffic has been silently dropped across the path for any possible reasons (e.g. firewall/ACLs or even lack of routes just as EHOSTUNREACH). It may also be the case that a router has generated the required ICMP, but another device in the path has dropped that ICMP (because for some reason people love blocking ICMP traffic)